# telegram-бот останавливается через час после включения

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

При запуске telegram-бота примерно через час aiogram пишет "Polling is stopped." и бот перестает работать. Почему?
Вот часть кода:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from random import randint

# ========= import requirements =============
from config import *
from buttons import *
from classes import *
from select_date import *
from handlers import extra, admin, user, callbacks, fsm_analog, brones
import startup as run

# =========== base variables =============
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# ========== handlers ============
isAdminData, userId, doing = extra.handlers(dp, types, isAdminData, userId, doing)
isAdminData, doing = admin.handlers(bot, dp, types, isAdminData, doing)
user.handlers(dp, types, userId, isAdminData)
doing = brones.handlers(bot, dp, types, userId, doing)
doing = callbacks.handlers(bot, dp, types, doing, userId, isAdminData)
doing = fsm_analog.handlers(dp, bot, types, randint, doing, run.is_auto)

# ============ polling ==============
print('start polling')
run.bot = bot
executor.start_polling(dp, timeout=999999, on_startup=run.on_startup)
```

Ошибки нету, просто выводит в консоль Polling is stopped и все.
Примечание: aiogram версии 2.25.2